# Mercurial clone failing at 99.x% everytime from multiple sources

Tags: python, mercurial

I'm getting interrupted errors when I try to clone a mercurial repository. I've tried from a couple of different sources to make sure it's not the repository's problem.

I'm running from cygwin on a windows 7 (64 bit) machine with administrator privileges.

Eg. command:
`hg clone --debug https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg mercurial-repo`

Similar problems when I try to clone through the tortoise GUI...

Appreciate any ideas!

UPDATE: Thanks to Tim in the comments, exiting my anti-virus completely (not just trying to disable within) solved the problem.

Error I'm getting:

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09) [GCC 4.5.3]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.5.2)
** Extensions loaded:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 38, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 28, in run
    sys.exit((dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])) or 0) & 255)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 65, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 88, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 743, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 514, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 833, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 804, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 740, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 475, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 1234, in clone
    branch=opts.get('branch'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 371, in clone
    destpeer.local().clone(srcpeer, heads=revs, stream=stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 2540, in clone
    return self.stream_in(remote, set(('revlogv1',)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 2473, in stream_in
    for chunk in util.filechunkiter(fp, limit=size):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 941, in filechunkiter
    s = nbytes and f.read(nbytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 422, in read
    s = self._rbuf + self._raw_read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 451, in _read_chunked
    value += self._safe_read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 649, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(11129 bytes read, 54407 more expected)
```

Comment: How reliable is your internet connection? This looks like a problem at the network level, not necessarily at the Mercurial level.

Comment: Also check your virus scanner. Perhaps it's tripping on something, preventing the download to complete?

Comment: Thanks guys, I had my antivirus disabled (as much as I could!) but I didnt have it closed completely. Exiting it sorted the problem. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the answer was posted by @tim-pietzcker in the second comment and @Shane states that this worked - I am just adding this as an answer so that the question no longer appears as "*Unanswered*".